# What are the requirements for a Powerpoint VSTO add-in manifest?

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, office-store

### Background / Goal

I have written a VSTO-based add-in for Microsoft Powerpoint. Due to the requirements of the add-in and the current JavaScript API surface for PowerPoint add-ins, I was unable to use the newer web-based format for add-ins as it did not have the capabilities I needed.

My goal is to be able to submit the VSTO add-in to AppSource so that it can make its way to the Office add-in store.

### Problem / Question

Now that my add-in is ready, I need to create a manifest file for it in order to publish it for others to consume.

However, all of the guidance I can find online points to a manifest format that appears to be geared toward the newer, web-based approaches rather than the older VSTO/COM-based approach.

So my question is:

- For a PowerPoint VSTO add-in that creates a Task Panel and a Ribbon entry (both in the format of controls within my solution), what are the requirements for an add-in manifest XML file?
- Are there any locations where one can see a template for VSTO add-ins rather than the newer web-based format?

### What I have Tried so Far

- I've looked in the documents for applicable examples but they all appear to refer to web-based add-in schema fields.
- I've published the VSTO project to a folder to attempt to use the `.manifest` or `.vsto` files during app registration, but I receive the error `Your manifest does not reference any supported Office Add-in namespace. The most recent version is http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1.`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to find a different marketplace. Microsoft is really bad for using confusing terms, or using the same terms to describe totally different things. AppSource uses web technology, not VSTO. Please read the Note in the purple box on this page: [Make your solutions available in AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store)
You also might find this opinion piece valuable: [The Future of Microsoft Office Add-In Development](https://www.breezetree.com/blog/future-of-office-add-in-development)

Comment: Thank you! I had missed the note on that page and spent an unfortunate amount of time trying to clarify and find a path. I wish I could have used the add-in approach but the powerpoint APIs I needed to use simply aren't available. This answer is 100% the correct answer in my case. Thanks for saving me more frustration!

Comment: It's unfortunate that Microsoft has never seen fit to support developers by providing an App Store for conventional add-ins. I would have used such a service!